# How to type ə (the schwa character) on macOS?

Tags: keyboard, internationalization

The [wikipedia article for *ə*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C6%8F) says, *“In MacOS with the U.S. Extended keyboard, the letters Ə ə are made with `Option`+`Shift`+`:` followed by `shift`+`A` or `a` respectively.”*

When I follow these instructions (on a Macbook Pro) I get: `ÚA` or `Úa`.

I know I can get it from the *Emoji & Symbols* panel, but I need a way to type it quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"US Extended" is now called the "ABC Extended" keyboard.  Schwa is made exactly the way that article and you describe.

The results you are getting are what happens when you are actually using a different input source, such as US or US International PC.  Make sure that the "flag" menu at the top right of the screen says ABC Extended.

Note that selecting an item in System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources does not do anything, you need to have the keyboard you want shown in the menu bar, where you can also actually set them.

If you prefer to switch keyboards without using the "flag" menu, you can set a keyboard shortcut for this in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Input Sources.

Comment: If it's necessary to include the menu-bar hint, then it seems adequate to also hint at the keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: You wrote "you *have* to set …in… menu bar". Minimal technicality: not *entirely* true.  But a user not aware of switching sources in menu might benefit from "SysPrefs>Kbd>ShortCuts>Input Sources" as well, where you *can* set a switch method also.

Comment: @TomGewecke, thanks, it works. Now, bonus points if anyone knows how to type ə on iOS? That's not so important to me, so I'm not going to open a new question, but if anyone know please reply here. :)

Comment: @Quinn Comendant For iOS you need to either use a hardware keyboard or download an app like Unicode Pad.  I think there are even apps especially for iPA.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work when I do that keyboard shortcut regardless of which version of English I choose, I just get Å

Comment: @Yuri.teacher.English. You are not using the correct input source.  It must be ABC Extended.  You must see that in the top right corner of the screen, not “us”.

Comment: I'm typing using ABC extended right now it says [A] ABC - Extended. I have a MacBook pro M1, maybe that's my problem.

Comment: @Yuri.teacher.English What do you see when. you type Option Shift ; by itself and let go?  It should be № in yellow.  Then type a.  The hardware doesn't matter.

Comment: With ; I get №. Ahhh! Now I get it! Yes, I'm getting ə. Thanks so much. But it's a bit complicated and quite a trick, though it does get easier as you I'm practicing.

Answer (score 1):

macOS text replacement is an easy and very flexible way to functionally remap one obscure character to another.

Here, for example is how to produce a schwa with ⌥S (normally ß):

1. Choose  > System Settings > Keyboard: Text Replacements…
2. Choose Edit > Emoji & Symbols.
3. Set Replace and With to whatever you like.

[image: macOS text replacement dialog box]

Comment: Some apps like Office do not use Apple's text replacement, so in those cases you have to duplicate the entries in their own system.